# sent bitcoin with a low fee to an address i cant access anymore

Tags: wallet, address, unconfirmed-transactions

whats up, as the title says, i sent bitcoin with a super low fee, after a couple of days I lost access to the account with the wallet i was sending to, and the bitcoin is still unconfirmed.

i was wondering if there was a way to cancel the unconfirmed transaction without having access to the wallet it is being sent to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fee was so low it may get rejected back to the address that sent the BTC. But you will have to wait a day or two more to see if that happens. Unless it confirms first, in which case, you'll need to get access to the RX address.